# Finding nearest point from POI in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point-of-interest

I have Point of Interest data in MySQL. This are the fields

> latitude,longitude,address,types

in which I have stored the data. Now i want to import it into PostGIS Database. But does it required geometry of this point??

which command is to be used to find nearest point with **radius** or **distance** ?

Comment: Can we remove the references to MySQL here? @polygeo? No one actually answered his original question? And it had nothing to do with PostGIS originally. To further confuse the matter MySQL now supports bounding box within and can do the same thing http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html#function_mbrwithin

Comment: @EvanCarroll that's not something that I think we should do without testing community support first. With so many votes already on the question and its answers I think we should use a Meta Q&A to see what the community wants to do with it. Let me know if you want me to ask that Meta Q&A or would prefer to ask it yourself.

Comment: I don't intend on asking the community. I'd just as soon close it or remove the reference. Sandeep seemed to have moved to use PostGIS, so it's clearly a relic by the comments on his answers, and there isn't a single answer here that entertains MySQL. So we should either be downvoting all of them, or chang the question so they matter (only because of sandeep's cooperation in the answers with PostGIS as a solution.)

Comment: Keep the word MYSQL there as it shows that data was in MYSQL database. Its moved from MySQL to POSTGIS. Question was how to move data from MySQL to POSTGIS and then find the nearest poi in PostGIS database. Its not confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Bring your data into PostgreSQL with something like [mysql_fdw](http://pgxn.org/dist/mysql_fdw/), or [other methods](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL).

Once you have this table, add a [geography column](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography), and populate the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE places ADD COLUMN geog geography(Point,4326);
UPDATE places SET geog = ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude);
```

Now select the nearest 10 places that are within 100 kms:

```
SELECT places.*, ST_Distance(geog, poi)/1000 AS distance_km
FROM places,
  (select ST_MakePoint(-90,47)::geography as poi) as poi
WHERE ST_DWithin(geog, poi, 100000)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(geog, poi)
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: 100 Kms is nothing but the radius ? Can i restrict the result with types ??

Comment: sure, just modify the `WHERE` part of the query. Also yes, `ST_DWithin` is a filter that uses a custom radius in metres.

Comment: How can i alter the table fields "latitude,longitude" to UNIQUE ?

Comment: These are [CONSTRAINTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html): `ALTER TABLE places ADD CONSTRAINT places_lat_lon_unique UNIQUE(latitude,longitude);`

Comment: Thanks
1 more question: we use this **'SELECT address From places WHERE types LIKE "%university%"'** MySQL Command when in **"types"** field there are other things also. Like in **"types"** field there are other data **"building,school,university,school_building"** with comma separated. I don't know which command is used in PostgreSQL in such type of situation?

Comment: there are several ways to do this: search using a regular expression `WHERE types ~ E'\\y(building|school)\\y''`, or convert the datatype to an array, and use more sophisticated array operators. You will probably need to ask a new question on stackoverflow if you want to know more about how to best search the data in your `types` column.

Answer (score 3):

You may not absolutely need to create geometries, but you will want to do it so that you can take advantage of indexes.  The below code works with Postgres 9.1+

```
 CREATE TABLE mypoints(gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, latitude double precision, longitude double precision, address varchar(100), types varchar (25), geom geometry(POINT, 4326));

 INSERT INTO mypoints (latitude, longitude, address, types, geom)VALUES (40.0,-90.0, '123 Main', 'house', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-90.0 40.0)',4326))
 INSERT INTO mypoints (latitude, longitude, address, types, geom)VALUES (41.0,-90.0, '123 Smith', 'house', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-90.0 41.0)',4326))
 INSERT INTO mypoints (latitude, longitude, address, types, geom)VALUES (42.0,-90.0, '123 Johnson', 'house', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-90.0 42.0)',4326))
 INSERT INTO mypoints (latitude, longitude, address, types, geom)VALUES (43.0,-90.0, '123 Oak', 'warehouse', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-90.0 43.0)',4326))
 INSERT INTO mypoints (latitude, longitude, address, types, geom)VALUES (44.0,-90.0, '123 Pine', 'store', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-90.0 44.0)',4326))
 INSERT INTO mypoints (latitude, longitude, address, types, geom)VALUES (45.0,-90.0, '123 Granite', 'factory', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-90.0 45.0)',4326))

  SELECT latitude, longitude, address, types
    FROM  mypoints
ORDER BY geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-90,47),4326)
 LIMIT 1;
```

If you are looking for all of the features/points within a certain distance, you could use St_DWithin()

Comment: Unfortunately, you shouldn't use simple distance operators on unprojected coordinates. Is 'POINT(-92.1 47.0)' closer or further to the POI than "123 Granite"? Although it's "Cartesian" distance is 2.1 (slightly further), it's distance on the spheroid makes it a closer point.

Comment: Good point Mike.  It would make sense to convert to a SRS that is true for distance or use the PostGIs geography type.  The above method would still work in a SRS like one of the UTM Zones.

Comment: @DaveF yes the '<->' operator works wonderfully in a UTM zone.

Comment: Thanks @DavidF. Can you tell me how can i Alter the table to change the Latitude and Longitude as Unique Key?? So that i can avoid to add the same co-ordinate again

Comment: I have multiple types in some fields like school,university. So If I want to extract the result of University within some distance how can i do that ??

In MySQL there is a command

'SELECT address From places WHERE types LIKE "%university%"'

So how can i do such type of thing in postgresql ??

Comment: The SQL is pretty much the same:  WHERE types = 'university'.  This would be an exact string match, and more efficient than a LIKE with double wildcards.

Comment: But we use this 

'SELECT address From places WHERE types LIKE "%university%"'

MySQL Command when in "types" field there are other things also. Like 
in "types" field there are other data "building,school,university,school_building" with comma separated.  

I don't know which command is used in PostgreSQL in such type of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use postgresql as database, and install postgis extension, and enable the extension for your database.

Then use a column similar to `location GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)` to store location.

Create a index for the column using GIST index type, similar as:

```
CREATE INDEX global_points_gix ON global_points USING GIST ( location );
```

Insert similar as:

```
INSERT INTO global_points (name, location)
VALUES ('Town', ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-110 30)') );
```

Query points within distance range similar as:

```
SELECT name FROM global_points
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-110 29)'), 1000000);
```

More details refer to:

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography