# Finding nearest points to POI with big data at Yelp?

Tags: proximity, big-data, yelp

Businesses often need to find nearest points to Points of Interest (POI).

For example, use Yelp to find restaurants within 10 mile distance. As a normal GIS practice, we solve this problem by using the GIS functions. There are lots of Q&As here on this topic and examples are:

1. [Finding points near points using PostgreSQL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61660)
2. [Finding nearest point from POI in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41242)

I wonder how about in the real business world, when data cannot fit in memory and high computational efficiency is a must.

How does Yelp solve these kind of spatial problem in their work?

Perhaps they use PostGIS, QGIS functions, etc to find nearest points near POI, or maybe they develop their own tools.

Comment: Looks like they use MySQL. http://www.slideshare.net/YelpEngineering/mysql-at-yelp

Comment: Thanks for your input. I looked through the slides and it seemed a very broad SQL application in Yelp, not sure if that is what they do for the geospatial part.

Comment: Perhaps the MySQL spatial extension, and appropriate indexing. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html